# Get node name for the executed custom action in magnolia cms

Tags: magnolia

I created a custom action in magnolia cms called MyAction.
I would like to get the node name of the page on which the action is executed. Instead I am getting an empty string for the page name.

This is the code:

```
package ch.xxx.module.versioning;

import info.magnolia.ui.api.action.Action;
import info.magnolia.ui.api.action.ActionExecutionException;

import javax.jcr.LoginException;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;

import info.magnolia.context.Context;
import info.magnolia.context.MgnlContext;



public class MyAction implements Action  {


    @Override
    public void execute() throws ActionExecutionException {
        String nodeName= "null";

        Context context = MgnlContext.getInstance();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = context.getJCRSession("website");
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Get root node
        try {
            nodeName = session.getRootNode().getName();
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Executed MyAction for node: " + nodeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your Magnolia version?

Comment: Magnolia version is 5.6.11

Comment: what you do: `nodeName = session.getRootNode().getName();` is getting you name of the root node (/), that name is always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ducaz035!

Here is the solution that worked for the custom action:

```
public class MyAction extends AbstractMultiItemAction<zzzVersioning>  {


public MyAction(zzzVersioning definition, JcrItemAdapter item, UiContext uiContext) {
                super(definition, item, uiContext);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }



@Override
public void execute() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Ran execute Action! " + getItems().get(0).getJcrItem().getName());
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



@Override
public void executeOnItem(JcrItemAdapter item) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
protected String getSuccessMessage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}



@Override
protected String getFailureMessage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Here is the code for the custom action definition:

```
public class zzzVersioning extends CommandActionDefinition {

    public zzzVersioning() {
        this.setImplementationClass(MyAction.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a constructor of your action and inject `info.magnolia.ui.vaadin.integration.jcr.JcrNodeAdapter` as a c-tor parameter.